# Can I get private constructor in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core

In .NET Framework such method exists:

```
public ConstructorInfo GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags bindingAttr,
    Binder binder,
    CallingConventions callConvention,
    Type[] types,
    ParameterModifier[] modifiers
)
```

But in .NET Core (1.1) I found only extension, which doesn't give me private constructor:

```
public static ConstructorInfo GetConstructor(this Type type, Type[] types)
```

So I'm wondering if I can somehow access and get private constructor in .NET Core.

Comment: Probably you are expected to use `GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors` and LINQ filter to find the desired constructor.

Comment: Yes thats the way to go, use the `TypeInfo` class in this older dotnet core version. The classic api call is implemented since dotnet core 2.0.

Comment: Yea, it works. Thanks.

Comment: @IvanStoev You might want to expand that to an answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have no experience with .net core, so it was a pure guess (hence a comment). May be you or someone else can provide a full fledged answer with proper references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `TypeInfo.DeclaredConstructors`.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.declaredconstructors?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-1.1#System_Reflection_TypeInfo_DeclaredConstructors) it applies to .NET Core 1.1 (and else).

You are expected to use `GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors` and LINQ filter to find the desired constructor.